# add different texts for specific values SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table students with name, subject and brothers, and I want add an text 'without brothers' if the values brothers is 0 or add 'brothers' if the student has more than 1 brother.

How I do this request?

excuse me for my english, I am learning.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your questions by providing some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
  name NVARCHAR(50) ,
  subj NVARCHAR(50) ,
  brother INT
)

INSERT  INTO @Table
VALUES  ( N'a', N's1', 1 ) ,
        ( N'b', N's1', 0 ) ,
        ( N'c', N's1', NULL ) ,
        ( N'd', N's1', 1 )

SELECT  name ,
        subj ,
        brother ,
        ( CASE WHEN ISNULL(brother, 0) > 0 THEN N'brothers'
               ELSE N'without brothers'
          END ) AS brotherStatus
FROM    @Table
```

Update :

```
SELECT  name ,
        subj ,
        brother ,
        CAST(ISNULL(brother, 0) AS NVARCHAR(5))
        + ( CASE WHEN ISNULL(brother, 0) > 0 THEN N' brothers'
                 ELSE N' without brothers'
            END ) AS brotherStatus
```